# What is the [soft-question] tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

That's it really. Not contesting anything, just asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, these are questions on *how to do physics in general* rather than *how to solve a particular problem*.

Such questions might ask about the list of literature for a certain subject. Or ask for general ideas useful in physics (or subject thereof). Or about history of a certain topic (but this is subtle: we'd in general like to have at least some physical content in the question, rather than just a historical). I guess you get the idea. Anyway, why don't you just [go look at those questions for yourself](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question)? :-)