# When should I use "soft-question" tag?

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the [soft-question] tag for?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/what-is-the-soft-question-tag-for)

I have seen "soft-question" tag on main site. I want to know its purpose. And, why is it here?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/273/2451