# Do we really need the soft-question tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

A conversation with DavidZ prompted this question (see [this question's](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/267339/how-do-i-build-a-transfer-cavity-system-for-lasers) comments).

Thinking about the [soft-question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) tag: when should it be used? Putting it on a [resource-recommendation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendation) question is kind of redundant...that's what the [resource-recommendation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendation) tag is for. Also, looking at [soft-question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) questions, most are on hold, closed, etc. Finally, it seems like having such a tag encourages such questions - and honestly, that's not what this site is about (as evidenced by the down-votes, etc).

So, with this in mind, I have three questions:

1. What is the [soft-question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) tag *supposed* to be used for? What uses are now appropriate?
2. Do we really need the [soft-question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) tag? I don't think so, but I want to know what others think.
3. If the answer to two is no, or not really, should we delete the soft-question tag?

Thanks! I'm interested to see what others think.

**Update:**

I might also add that while I definitely agree with DavidZ's answer, I'd like to see what the community thinks, and hopefully everyone will come to a consensus.

Comment: Previous discussion: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/7551/

Answer (score 4):

My *personal* viewpoint: there are no valid uses for [soft-question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) and we should burninate it (i.e. purge it from the system and forbid future use).

In my experience, basically all questions which are given the [soft-question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) tag are either off topic, or don't really need the tag. I'm not entirely sure [what it means for a question to be soft](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/what-is-the-soft-question-tag-for), anyway, but the questions we do allow that would fit most people's definition of "soft" are already identified by more focused tags like [resource-recommendation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendation).

If this answer emerges as the community consensus, we (mods) will arrange to have the tag removed.

Comment: I agree. +1. I'm interested to see what the rest of the community thinks.

Comment: I don't think we should be anywhere that trigger-happy. There's currently [460+](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bsoft-question%5d%20closed%3ano%20score%3a1) upvoted, open questions with the tag. That's a *very* broad brush to use on a lot of questions. On the other hand, there's a fair number of questions there that don't really need the tag, and if after it gets removed then everything left there is off-topic, then sure, yeah, burninate it.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty From a sampling of the first page, all the question I see on that list either shouldn't have the tag IMO or are off topic.

Comment: @DavidZ That may be. But the first page is very rarely a good sample, and there are a *lot* of questions.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Why would the most recent questions not be a good sample? In any case, perhaps we can discuss this in chat sometime (not now, I don't have time) at which time I will take a more comprehensive look through the list, but in the meantime I would pose this question: which questions do you think need to have the tag and are also on topic?

Comment: I think e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235581), [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262880), [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231837), [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/223359), or [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221873) questions do benefit from the tag, but again (i) that's a very partial look at the list, (ii) it's a subjective assessment, and (iii) it is indeed a meta tag, so we could argue for days with no agreement. I don't think the tag causes that much harm, either, though.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Indeed it is subjective; I believe none of those questions should have the tag. That being said, I think the fact that posts like this keep coming up is evidence of the harm the tag causes. (I guess to a defender of the tag, this wouldn't really be _harm_, exactly, but my point is more that "it doesn't really matter so we don't need to do anything" isn't a viable argument.)

Comment: No, that's not my argument. I'm saying that (i) I feel the posts are on topic, (ii) the tag is not (or at least not always) harmful - with both points obviously subjective. I'm also saying, on a bit more objective track, (iii) that I think straight burnination is too drastic an action for something with that many (open, score>0) posts in it. In any case, let's wait and see how the votes look like.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, looking at the questions you linked, they seem like they could be tagged with the physics subject they are discussing, and don't need a soft-question tag at all. Also, I think the tag is harmful. I think people will take these types of questions a little less seriously, and it certainly also seems to be like the homework tag (i.e., it's bad, let's slap that tag on) or it fits with the resource-recommendation tag. Finally, burnination doesn't mean the good posts get deleted...just retagged.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I'm not sure I buy that argument against burnination; after all, the reason the functionality exists is to deal with tags that have too many posts to make editing them out viable. That being said, if people object to burnination, I would also be okay with simply preventing use of the tag on new questions.

Comment: @DavidZ, do you think it would be okay to go through the soft-question tag and retag where I can (i.e., where it is clear) five at a time, to start clearing the tag of stuff that shouldn't be in there?

Comment: @heather Well, I _personally_ wouldn't mind, but I think it's better not to. After all, I figure this debate ends one of two ways: either we decide to eliminate the tag, in which case it'll be done all at once by the SE team, or we don't, in which case editing out the tag will be pointless.

Comment: @DavidZ, I understand, I was just wondering if maybe editing out the questions that don't really belong would allow people to make more reasoned comments about the situation (no reference to anyone in particular, I mean in terms of gathering data of how many are on hold, etc). But, as you say, probably not the best idea.

Comment: @heather The issue with that is deciding which questions the tag does or doesn't really belong on. It seems not to be the sort of thing one person should decide on their own.

Comment: @DavidZ, okay, makes sense.

Comment: It seems that this is a question for only 2 -3 people

Comment: I only have one issue with burninating the tag. Someone will have to go through the list of questions under it and find appropriate tags for at least all the soft questions with no other tags. If you can find someone to do that and if that person isn't me, then you have my blessing to get rid of it

Comment: Also, that reinforces the idea that all questions should be tagged in at least two subjects when they are created. In case one tag is burned

Comment: @Jim Don't worry, I'd have that task covered. In any case, soft-question is a "meta tag" which means (among other things) that it should never be the only tag on a question. That's the only reason we're considering this proposal. This would never happen to a tag like [tag:material-science].

Answer (score -2):

This question is not about the usefulness of this tag, but about the usefulness of its topic.

- [The MathSE finds it useful.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) They are the [best going](http://stackexchange.com/sites) StackExchange site after the SO.
- [The MathOverflow, too,](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/soft-question) despite they are a grad-level community with quite harsh moderation customs, having many Big Names between them.

Now think, which direction find you better to follow.

[Additional info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/1783163) about the main sociological structure of the SE sites.

Comment: While I respect your opinion, I'd like to make two points. 1. Just because other sites do it does not necessarily mean we should do it. Yes, it's a plus, but that doesn't have to do with anything, really. 2. The questions that normally fall under soft-question are either off-topic or under resource-recommendation. I can't think of a single question that would be legitimately tagged soft-question without falling into one of those two categories. So, why keep the tag? This isn't really answer, it is more a "others do it so we should too".

Comment: @heather Yes, it is an answer - because it explains very clearly, why should we follow them, too.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Why should we? Your answer just lists two sites that use it! I might add that just because there are highly voted soft-question questions doesn't mean a thing. Some of those are locked, as historic but not on-topic.

Comment: @heather Yes, the flagships of the SE network.

Comment: Those two are *not* flagships. Stack overflow is the flagship. And even if they were, who cares? Physics.SE is different from both. We have our own set of users and topics. We have our own tags.

Comment: @heather I explained in the answer, why are they flagships. I've also explained in the last sentence, why leads your suggestion to destruction.

Comment: You have not. What, they are flagships because they have the second biggest square? A flagship is the leading ship - the first. Stack overflow was the first. But that is beside the point. Your last sentence, "Now think, which direction find you better to follow" says nothing. I think it's best to follow the direction that is best for physics.SE!

Comment: While I'm mostly in favour of keeping the tag, there is nothing in this answer that actually presents a working argument for that. You're welcome to think otherwise but have a solidly earned -1 from me.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, I just would like you to know, I found your comments very constructive below DavidZ's answer...would you mind posting an answer of your own?

Comment: @heather This is why I explained in the last sentence, why should a site be the possible most widely open.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't even understand that comment. A site should be "most widely open"? So we should become a forum, the very thing stack exchange was built not to be? Because that's the most "widely open"! Sometimes its best *not* to have that open-ness (again, as evidenced by stack exchange).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I am sorry to hear. I think the well-goingness of the site is a strong argument.

Comment: @heather No, I didn't say that. I can't see any evidence, why a closed site with continously narrowed topic, ruled by an inbreed inner circle randomly picking and closing most questions would be better as an open site, full with life, with a broad topic where everybody can get the answer to his/her questions. I think your suggestion takes the things in the first direction, this is why I am for the clear rules and for the openness.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying the comment, then?

Comment: And just because this site is doing well doesn't mean much either. Would you say, using that argument, that we don't need to do any work on the homework policy? On improving this site at all? Because it's going well, we don't need to do more work to improve it?

Comment: Regarding the "well-going"ness of maths.se, I think it's a *terrible* argument. The reasons for that site's "success" in terms of throughput are completely different to what many/most users here would consider success for this site. I for one would pretty much stop participating if the level of questions dropped to what it is on maths.se, and I suspect most professional users here would do much the same.

Comment: May I also ask why you linked to an answer talking about help vampires, rep whores, apathics, and normal users? If you are implying I am being unhelpful here, I go through the review queues, and try to help this site, and I think this is an honest question. And Emilio Pisanty is arguably one of the best users on this site!

Comment: Finally, questions are not arbitrarily closed. It sounds like you want a math.se style place, and that would be terrible! I think, as Emilio Pisanty said, most users here now would leave.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty What I would find very unfortunate. The problem is that in the physics enthusisasts/professionals there are significantly different groups in their preferences, and their wishes are contradictory. If the communities of the MathSE and the MO had to share the same site, it had leaded probably to a not really well-going site like the current PhysSE. But, I can see 2 solutions for that: 1) The creation of a MO-like PSE site 2) using euphemistic tagging to separate the LQ/enthusisast/soft questions from the HQ ones.

Comment: @heather Because they describe the main sociological structure of the SE sites. As you try to hold together the possible largest and possible highest Q community, you should consider it.

Comment: @peterh, I'm not sure that makes sense. I think physics.SE is doing well, and I think we keep a good balance between simple and complex questions. I think the soft question tag is just a bad idea period. And I also think we should not encourage the splitting of physics.SE into physics and physics overflow.

Comment: And the sociological structure has nothing to do with this question. And what do you mean by the largest community? Physics is *not* the highest Q community...that goes, once again, to stack overflow. And I think it's interesting to note that stack overflow does *not* have the soft question tag.

Comment: @heather It is because you are a new account, a new star in the sky of the PSE, with a *surprisingly* fast appearance. But you probably don't have enough experience from the sociological structure and from the preferences of the different groups here, thus you prefer your own and don't understand others. I think you need some months, some years to understand the things here correctly.

Comment: You can daydream all you want, but I personally find your level of understanding of how the communities here, at MSE, and at MO, actually work to be remarkably off-target. (The fact that you're using a post that's exclusively about SO as a stand-in for the whole of SE puts you even further down the track.) I won't argue here further - I just wish I could downvote again.

Comment: @peterh, no need to be poetic. I just enjoy this site and learning about physics. And I have spent (probably too much) time reading meta discussions on the mother meta and this meta; as such, I am familiar with the term rep whore and help vampire. And, as for months/years...I have been on this site for a little over a month. Sure, I'm not as experienced as many high rep users, but I don't think I need years to understand everything.

Comment: @heather Yes, but the SO has a lot of additional sites, more than 50% of the sites of the SE network are IT-oriented, thus they don't need it. From a physics site, there is only one.

Comment: @heather You can be sure, he read already the first. There is no need to replay, or you risk our comments will go to the chat.

Comment: @peterh, the point remains. If you want to point to "flagships" I will point to *the* flagship which doesn't use the soft-question tag.

Comment: @heather Yes, I think you are right, you read probably a *lot* of meta discussions already, it is very clear to me from the first moment.

Comment: @heather Read [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8915/do-we-really-need-the-soft-question-tag/9066#comment33771_9066) again then.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Although I linked a SO post, what it states, is independent from the actual site. All of the sites I know, have the same structure. What is, to me, is not a problem. The wellgoing of the MathSE is because they allow group (2) and (3) to play. Doing that, they produce a lot of content, attracting a lot of visitors, also the HQ content between them. If you see the *mean quality* of the MathSE, yes it is clearly lower as the PSE, but if you see the *size of the HQ content*, it is clearly much higher. This is my daydream: to find a solution to make it enjoyable for everybody.

Comment: As I said, feel free to daydream. I just don't see you finding such a solution if you don't start listening to people, though.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Even if it seems now as a daydream, surely nothing will happen if you at least not communicate it. From you second sentence: I would be happy to listen you in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).